# How to add *SVG* file inside script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want the html document to give an svg output or draw a circle 
 whenever i give an input "draw a circle".But something is not right.
What error am I doing in this code?
It is not showing me the expected output.

```
 `` <html>
<input id="inputuser">
<script>
if(inputuser="Show a circle"){
<svg width="100" height="100">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
 Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> }
</script>
</html>``
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? javascript can parse markup if you invoke a parser.

Comment: You are **mixing** JavaScript and HTML

Comment: What do you mean by invoke parser @Robert Longson

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using javascript

**Example solution**

```js
var content = `<svg width="100" height="100">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>`;


document.getElementById('inputuser').addEventListener('input', updateValue);;

function updateValue(e) {
  var iu = document.getElementById('inputuser');
  if(iu.value === "Show a circle"){
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = content;
 }
}
```

```html
<p>Type "Show a circle" in the input field</p>

<input id="inputuser"/>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: What did you do can you plz explain me a bit why wasn't my code working before and why is your code working?

Comment: and When is `const` used? and why is it used?

Comment: you can use var instead of const. updated the solution

Comment: ok and why did used `` to write the svg?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// CREATING ELEMENTS 'svg' AND 'circle'.

var elem = document.createElement("svg"); 
var circle = document.createElement("circle"); 

// GIVING ATTRIBUTES TO ELEMENT
elem.setAttribute("width", 100); elem.setAttribute("height", 100); 
circle.setAttribute("cx", 50); circle.setAttribute("cy", 50); 
circle.setAttribute("stroke", "green"); circle.setAttribute("stroke-width", 4); 
circle.setAttribute("fill", "yellow"); 

// APPENDING ELEMENTS
document.body.appendChild(elem); 
document.body.elem.appendChild(circle);
```

First of all create an element named `svg` give it some attribute and append it to body and finally create another element `circle` and append it to svg element.

Or you can directly use the code in this way.

```
document.write("<svg width="100" height="100">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
 Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>");
```

**WARNING: IT WILL REPLACE BODY ELEMENT**
Have a good day :-)

Answer (score 0):

- You are **mixing** JavaScript and HTML
- You are not listening on what happens in 'inputuser'

```html
<input id="inputuser"><span id="response"></span>
<script>
  inputuser.onkeyup = (event) => {
    if (inputuser.value == "circle") {
      response.innerHTML = `<svg width="50" height="50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow"/></svg>`
    } else {
      response.innerHTML = "type: 'circle'";
    }
  }
</script>
```

- this works because Browsers create **global** variables, with the same name, for `id=` definitions on DOM elements.